# C++ char array and vector string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I want to copy the words in the chars array to the vector string.I wrote the following code and it gives me errors that string,vector,words wasn't declared in this scope,and I declared the function in the header file can you help??

here is the code:

```
vector<string> split(char sentence[])
{
    vector<string> ans(100);
    int count=0;
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<sentence.size();i++)
    {
    if(sentence[i]==' ')
        count=count+1;
    ans[count]=ans[count]+sentence[i];
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: [Splitting a string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c)

Comment: `vector` and `string` usually live in the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 3):

A `char[]` is a primitive type, and does not have member functions, for example no such thing as `.size()`...

Are you sure you know what you are doing? This, and the missing of headers (which Luchian already commented on) give the impression you don't, really...

Comment: Note also that the primitive type `char[]` is used nowhere in the code. The actual type of the parameter is `char*`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Actually, the language lawyer in me would like to disagree on that one, as it is *declared* as `char[]`. In the end, it doesn't make a difference in the context of the question. You might be more correct, I might be more understandable, but in any case, `sentence.size()` is broken code.

Comment: The point is that the type of `sentence` is `char*`, not `char[]`. You're saying that `char[]` doesn't have `size` member, but that is technically irrelevant here.

Comment: Konrad and avakar are correct - the type of `sentence` *is* `char *`. I was only aware of the practical implications of passing an array as parameter (e.g. that you cannot take `sizeof` to determine its length anymore), not that it actually implied a type change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the headers `<vector>` and `<string>` and qualify the use with `std::` or use `using` directives. Full name qualification should be preferred:

```
std::string
std::vector
```

EDIT: I didn't notice the `char*::size` mistake, because I was focused on the error message you posted ("wasn't declared in this scope"). Some thought this deserved a downvote... whatever.

Comment: @avakar "it gives me errors that string,vector,words wasn't declared in this scope" so I missed one.

Comment: Just for the record, I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You really ought to just use a built-in library or something, and split the string with a regular expression.

Instead of using a `char[]` use a `string`.  Its easy to convert `char[]` to that, and it was probably a string to begin with, so you should cut that out earlier.

To form your `vector<string>`, all you have to do is this:

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector.h>

using namespace std;

vector<string> split(string s){
    regex r ("\\w+"); //regex matches whole words, (greedy, so no fragment words)
    regex_iterator<string::iterator> rit ( s.begin(), s.end(), r );
    regex_iterator<string::iterator> rend; //iterators to iterate thru words
    vector<string> result<regex_iterator>(rit, rend);
    return result;  //iterates through the matches to fill the vector
}
```

That would probably need one or two bugs worked out (I'm just a little rusty), and could also be compacted down considerably using inline statements.

Remember: The magic of c++ comes in two forms: iterators and inline statements.